# Outlook365 EWS streaming notifications | new user first event

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365, ews-managed-api

I am writing a synchronisation tool which is going to send all the received and sent email messages to our PHP application built in CakePHP. For this I am making use of [Streaming Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Now, for every smtp address I want to listen to I am creating a new service which is going to listen to "created" events in the "Inbox"  and "SentItems" folder. I am doing this via an account that has the right to impersonate all these accounts.

**The folders and events I'm talking about** (C#)

```
// The folders we want to listen to
FolderId[] folderIds = new FolderId[] {
    WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
    WellKnownFolderName.SentItems
};
// The event types we want to listen to
EventType[] eventTypes = new EventType[] {
    EventType.Created
};
```

Also, we are using Outlook365 which can be accessed via https://portal.outlook365.com where I can then login. When I create a new user in the "Outlook365" I can login to that freshly created account.

But, this is where my problem arises. When I start the tool and open my SubscriptionStreamConnection to that smtp address, it immediately triggers an event of the type `ItemEvent`. So, I am assuming that is a valid event, just like a newly created email message in the inbox and sentitems folder. But this first event does not contain all the data I am asking for and only happens once! The second time I listen to the account the event isn't triggered, so I assume this is some sort of "Create inbox" event, but I am not sure how I can distinguish this from a normal event.

**What I am asking for** (C#)

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(
    BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
    EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId,
    // Basic data
    EmailMessageSchema.Subject,
    EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody,
    EmailMessageSchema.ConversationId,
    EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived,
    EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeSent,
    // Sender and recipient data
    EmailMessageSchema.From,
    EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.CcRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.BccRecipients
    );
```

**What I am receiving** (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="939" MinorBuildNumber="16" Version="V2_11" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:Items>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ItemId Id="AA/BB/CC/DD=" ChangeKey="AA/BB" />
                <t:DateTimeReceived>2014-05-13T09:47:44Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
                <t:DateTimeSent>2014-05-13T09:47:44Z</t:DateTimeSent>
                <t:ConversationId Id="AA=" />
                <t:InternetMessageId><11aa@AMXPR07MB104.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com></t:InternetMessageId>
              </t:Message>
            </m:Items>
          </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:GetItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

*Please note: I changed the ID's for the sake of readability, I kept the `/` in place, just in case they mean something*.

As you can see the XML response does not contain all the properties I am asking for, a normal event however (when I send an email to that new account) I do receive a complete response, like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="939" MinorBuildNumber="16" Version="V2_11" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:Items>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ItemId Id="AA/BB/CC/DE=" ChangeKey="AA/BB" />
                <t:Subject>My random test!</t:Subject>
                <t:DateTimeReceived>2014-05-13T10:25:55Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
                <t:DateTimeSent>2014-05-13T10:25:38Z</t:DateTimeSent>
                <t:ConversationId Id="AA/LEGY=" />
                <t:UniqueBody BodyType="Text" IsTruncated="false">Hello World</t:UniqueBody>
                <t:ToRecipients>
                  <t:Mailbox>
                    <t:Name>a10 Test</t:Name>
                    <t:EmailAddress>a10@mytestdomain.nl</t:EmailAddress>
                    <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
                    <t:MailboxType>Mailbox</t:MailboxType>
                  </t:Mailbox>
                </t:ToRecipients>
                <t:From>
                  <t:Mailbox>
                    <t:Name>My Name - Company</t:Name>
                    <t:EmailAddress>canttell@example.com</t:EmailAddress>
                    <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
                    <t:MailboxType>OneOff</t:MailboxType>
                  </t:Mailbox>
                </t:From>
                <t:InternetMessageId><AA00@SRV-01.mycompany.local></t:InternetMessageId>
              </t:Message>
            </m:Items>
          </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:GetItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

Of course I can add a simple check if for example the Subject exists in this event, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Just to clarify, some my project "properties"  are as follows:

- I am connection to outlook365.com
- I am making use of C# with the .NET4.5 framework and the latest EWS API
- I have one user that can impersonate all other users, so that the program does not need to know all passwords
- I add all the ImpersonatedUserId's I want to listen to, each of those impersonated users has their own service (I think this info is obsolete, but it might help you)
- In my "OnNotificationEvent" I try to get the Item by it's ID (in a new thread, so that the main program can continue)

This is the code of the method that handles the event:

```
protected void _OnExchangeNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = (StreamingSubscriptionConnection)sender;
    StreamingSubscription subscription = args.Subscription;

    // Loop through all item-related events. 
    foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
    {
        // if the notification is NOT an item event, skip the event
        if (!(notification is ItemEvent))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Start a new thread so the main program can continue
        Thread exchangeToCrmThread = new Thread(() => this._handleExchangeEventToCrm((ItemEvent)notification, args));
        exchangeToCrmThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Note the `_handleExchangeEventToCrm` method, this methods actually tries to get the EmailMessage (as per PropertySet above).

## My question

*Just to clarify*

Why is a new user triggering an `ItemEvent` when I am listening to it via a `StreamingSubscribtion` for the VERY FIRST time? In other words, how can I distinguish a "normal" email sent/received event from any other event which apparently is an "ItemEvent" as well?

I suspect it has to do with "mailbox creation", but I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

*If anything is unclear, please ask so that I can clarify my question*

Answer (score 1):

I just repro'd this and found that the first item I received on a new mailbox was a folder associated item (FAI). So nothing appears in my inbox in OWA/Outlook, but I received a notification for a CreatedEvent in my Inbox. You can determine that it's a folder associated item by checking the IsAssociated element. If IsAssociated is true, it's not a normal message.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you put in this to check it! I will give it a go and mark it as the answer if it did indeed solve it for me. I can not tell it right now though since we are at our Office365 users limit. So it might take a while before I can mark it for certain. +1 for you though!